# Bitmap image as a pattern for Leaflet.js map

Tags: svg, bitmap, leaflet

I am using [Leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/) to generate a map from geoJSON file. I'd like to fill some of the areas with a pattern. I've found a plugin ([Leaflet.pattern](https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern)) and tweaked it a bit to add support for bitmap images. It seems to work correctly, the SVG `<defs>` part seems to be OK

```
<pattern id="25" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image stroke="none" fill="none" pointer-events="none" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"></image>
</pattern>
```

The `<g>`bit looks like this:

```
<g>
    <path 
      stroke-linejoin="round" 
      stroke-linecap="round" 
      fill-rule="evenodd" 
      stroke="#000" 
      stroke-opacity="1" 
      stroke-width="0.5" 
      fill="url(#25)" 
      fill-opacity="0.9" 
      class="leaflet-clickable" 
      d="M-23 200L-27 200L-27 191L-29 188L-29 184L-24 179L-19 177L-1 187L1 180L5 194L19 194L19 201L17 204L13 205L7 202L5 205L-8 199L-10 202L-17 198z">
    </path>
</g>
```

The problem is that the pattern is not there.

But when I copy the generated SVG and open it on its own the pattern is there.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Could you supply a testcase on JSfiddle or preferrably [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) which reproduces your problem?

Comment: It's problematic, at the moment - it's tricky to separate just this bit of code...